# django.db.utils.InterfaceError:('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) )

Tags: sql-server, django

I have a Django web app with azure sql server,i move the code from one laptop to another and suddenly i got django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') imidatly after starting the web server

I have been able to isolate the problem , and realized it coming from the db connection in setting.py , i tried to run simple python quay from the console and it worked

I compared my settings in the ODBC data source to my old laptop and it looks the same ,

**SOLVED-- i noticed that only diffrence was that in my old laptop i have also 
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, i installed this as well and it worked**

I am using :
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Any ideas?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'XXXXXX',
        'Trusted_Connection':'No',       
        'HOST' : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        'DRIVER': '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extra_params': 'APP=Setting.py',
        },
        'AUTOCOMMIT' : True ,
        'USER' : 'XXXXXXX',
        'PASSWORD' : 'XXXXXXX'
          }}
```

Comment: *"I tried all the solutions i saw online with no luck"* We need to therefore know what "all the solutions" are that you tried, so that we don't ask you to try them again.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to change the odbc setting on my windows

Answer (score 3):

I needed to install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567 odbc my SQL 17 driver.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
'DRIVER': '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
```

use

```
'DRIVER': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct version of the OBDC Driver

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16